# Cumulative distribution function using Cauchy Formula

Tags: probability, random-variables

I really need assistance solving this problem.
Here's the question:
The cumulative distribution function of a random varible X is $$F(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan x}{\pi}.$$ Compute $P(X> -0.4|X< 3.25)$.

Here's what I tried to do:
$$
P(X=3.25)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan 3.25}{\pi}
$$
$$
P(X=-0.4)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan -0.4}{\pi}
$$
Then $[P(X=3.25)-P(X=-0.4)]/P(X=3.25) = 0.31$ which is nowhere near the possible answer for this multiple choices problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should review your materials about the definition of the cumulative distribution function. It does *not* give you the probability of a single value. That said, the answer actually *is* $\frac{F(3.25)-F(-0.4)}{F(3.25)}$. I don't know what went wrong in your calculation.

Comment: You are certainly right!
I am clueless cause I had to skip classes due to health problems and now I am totally lost.
Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Mr Ian, thanks again!
Doing the calculations again I get the answer 0.58134. Sounds good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what a cdf is.  $F(x)$ is the probability that the associated random variable $X$ is less than or equal to $x,$ not the probability that $X=x.$

In this example, the cdf is continuous, so $P(X=x)$ equals $0$ for any specific $x.$ As a result, we have

$$P(X\le x)=P(X\lt x)=F(x)$$

and

$$P(X\ge x)=P(X\gt x)=1-F(x).$$

So

\begin{align}P(X\gt−0.4\mid X\lt3.25)&=\frac{P(X\gt-0.4\text{ and }X\lt 3.25)}{P(X\lt 3.25)}
\\&=\frac{F(3.25)-F(-0.4)}{F(3.25)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Hello there Mr. Mitchell!
Thanks for the enlightenment! Using the computation you have shown me I get the answer 0.58134. Sounds good?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: You wrote $f$ and should have written $F$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks -- it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

First, recall that
$$
P(X>-0.4\mid X<3.25)=\frac{P(X>-0.4,\ X<3.25)}{P(X<3.25)}.
$$

So, the point here is to compute each of these quantities using the given CDF.

The denominator is easy, since it coincides with the definition of the CDF. (Well, nearly -- technically, $F(3.25)=P(X\leq3.25)$; but, because the CDF is continuous there, we get that $P(X=3.25)=0$ and therefore $F(3.25)=P(X<3.25)$ as well.)

For the numerator, note that
$$
P(X>-0.4,\ X<3.25)=P(X<3.25)-P(X\leq-0.4).
$$

Comment: Technically the denominator doesn't *coincide* with the definition of the CDF, in the usual definition of the CDF. (It would in some Russian literature, but I digress.) But $P(X=3.25)=0$ because of continuity...

Comment: Hello Mr. Nick!
First of all, thanks for the support you have provided so far. I guess my main problem here is that since I had to skip few classes I'm totally lost on how to compute the probabilities.
I will try harder!